# Why does this Using() give me an error?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, using

I am trying to open an (hundreds actually) excel file(s). I open the application but want to use the Using() functionality around each of the workbooks I open. Why is this resulting in an error?

```
using (Excel.Workbook wbXL = appXL.Workbooks.Open(_sourceFullPath, Type.Missing, Excel.XlFileAccess.xlReadOnly))
{
    //stuff with wbXL
}
```

using gets the red underline and says "'Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel.Workbook':Type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'.

How to make this work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Pretty much what it says - you can only use `using` with classes that implement IDisposable, so that under the covers the compiler knows which function to call on finalisation - `yourclass.Dispose()`. The Excel interop classes don't implement this.

So you've got two choices:

1. Write your own wrapper class for Excel.Workbook that implements IDispose and either exposes the object itself to call methods on, or wraps those methods too, e.g.

   ```
   public class DisposableWorkbook : IDisposable
   {
       private Excel.Workbook _workbook = null;

       public DisposableWorkbook(Excel.Application appXL, String path,
                                 NotSureOfType otherArgument,
                                 Excel.XlFileAccess access)
       {
           _workbook = appXL.Workbooks.Open(path, otherArgument, access);
       }

       public Excel.Workbook Workbook
       {
           get { return _workbook; }
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           if (workbook != null)
           {
               workbook.Close(Excel.XlSaveAction.xlDoNotSaveChanges,
                              workbookToClose);
               workbook = null;
           }
       }
   }

   using (DisposableWorkbook dwbXL = new DisposableWorkbook(appXL,
             _sourceFullPath, Type.Missing, Excel.XlFileAccess.xlReadOnly))
   {
        Excel.Workbook wbXL = dwbXL.Workbook;
        // stuff with wbXL
   }
   ```
2. Implement `using` yourself, e.g.

   ```
   Excel.Workbook wbXL = null;
   try
   {
       wbxl = appXL.Workbooks.Open(_sourceFullPath, Type.Missing,
                                   Excel.XlFileAccess.xlReadOnly);
       //stuff with wbXL
   }
   finally
   {
       if (wbxl != null) wbxl.Close();
   }
   ```

Comment: So as it stands I call `wbXL.Close(Excel.XlSaveAction.xlDoNotSaveChanges, workbookToClose);` when I'm done with my wbXL. This is sufficient for GC? A using statement wouldn't be any "better"?

Comment: @Brad the using statement compiles into a try-finally anyway, so it's pretty much the same.

Comment: Oh ok well that's not as fancy as I was expecting it to be. Cool! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The using statement includes a try-finally so that it gets closed even on exception - I think that's all, I don't think it forces GC no. If there's a better way to clean up the object (e.g. force-release the COM object) somewhere in System.Runtime.Interop then you can call that too, sure, but I don't know of one myself.

Comment: ok one more thing! Right now I access all these things (opening the excel, closing it, interacting with excel) from within an csActiveFile class. I call that class and those methods from a form. Is this what you mean by wrapper class?

Comment: No, but that might do: I meant any class that implements IDisposable and manages the lifetime of the Excel object. I'll type something up quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Any item in a `using` statement must implement the `IDisposable` interface.  I haven't got the documentation to hand, but I'll guess `Excel.Workbook` doesn't implement this interface.

Answer (score 1):

[using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

`Excel.Workbook` does not implement `IDisposable`, so you can't use `using` for it..

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it work.

The `using` block is used to free resources from objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface as quickly and as safely as possible.

`Excel.Workbook` does not implement `IDisposable` so you can't declare it for use in a `using` block.

Answer (score -1):

```
Businessmanger emb = new Businessmanger();
        try
        {


            TempData["deparmentList"] = Deplist;
            return PartialView("create");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


            throw;
        }
        finally {
            //object dispose here
                            ((IDisposable)emb).Dispose();
        }
```